# undefined local variable or method `recipient_email'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, flash

I'm trying to force a flash method out of my model so I can display something nicer than the standard rails error.

I have this method in my model, `invitation.rb`:

```
def recipient_is_not_registered
  if User.find_by_email(recipient_email)
    false
  else
    true
  end
end
```

I call it with a `before_create :recipient_is_not_registered` callback and it returns false if the `recipient_email` has already been registered in the database as a User.  This should trigger the `if @invitation.save` as false, which goes down the `else` branch, displaying the flash message.

In my `invitations_controller.rb` I have:

```
def create
  @invitation = Invitation.new(invitation_params)
  @invitation.sender = current_user
  if @invitation.save
    redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Invitation was successfully created.'
  else
    flash[:notice] = "The email address #{recipient_email} has already been registered."
  end
end
```

This gives me the aforementioned error: ``` undefined local variable or method ``recipient_email' ```

I have tried various iterations of `Invitation.recipient_email` to no avail.

There are 2 questions.

1. Resolve the NameError.
2. Discover why the flash isn't being displayed.

Comment: `I have tried various iterations of Invitation.recipient_email to no avail.` could you please include these in your question.

Comment: What *is* `recipient_email` and where is it defined?

Comment: Is `recipient_email` an attribute or a method? Can you also include your schema file too.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to access a param (recipient_email) that is not defined in your Model. Is recipient_email a column in your Invitations SQL table?

Comment: `flash[:notice]` will work on redirect. If you are rendering template from `else` condition, use `flash[:now]`

Comment: @Alfie - some I have tried to insert right before if '@invitation.save are:
'@invitation.recipient_email = recipient_email
recipient_email = invitation.recipient_email
etc...

recipient_email is a row in the Invitations table and in the Invitations model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def create
  @invitation = Invitation.new(invitation_params)
  @invitation.sender = current_user
  if @invitation.save
    redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Invitation was successfully created.'
  else
    flash[:notice] = "The email address #{@invitation.recipient_email} has already been registered."
  end
end
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: That gives me "undefined method `email' for #Invitation'.

Comment: Try to use @invitation.recipient_email. Let me know about this.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you provided, looks like `recipient_email` is an attribute of `Invitation`, which is going to be available within the `Invitation` only.

Try the following:

```
def create
  @invitation = Invitation.new(invitation_params)
  @invitation.sender = current_user

  if @invitation.save
    redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Invitation was successfully created.'
  else
    flash[:notice] = "The email address #{@invitation.recipient_email} has already been registered."
  end
end
```

Comment: Upvoted because it was right answer, but @Muhamad Akbar Bin Widayat got there first.